# Which of these two sentences is (more) correct?

Tags: commas

"The average number and total number of dogs and cats are presented in the following table."

"The average number, and total number, of dogs and cats are presented in the following table."

The table has four entries: average number of dogs, average number of cats, total number of dogs, total number of cats.

Comment: Some statistics on dog and cat ownership are shown in the following table.

Comment: @Jim I agree that would be preferable. However, I'm writing in the context of correcting someone else's work, so my main concern is to work out whether the student has made an error. If so, I'd ideally like to be able to give the error a name or refer the student to a webpage explaining more about it.

Comment: I prefer the first for the reasons given by Shoe. But you could shorten it to "The averages & totals for (each of) dogs and cats ...". Adding "each of" would address the point made by Mark, but, as I said in my comment to his answer, is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Neither sentence is more correct than the other. It depends on how you wish to present your information to the reader. The second sentence uses delimiting commas, which *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p1745) describes as marking an element that is:

> ... set apart from the main part of the sentence, usually indicating
>   that it is in some sense less central to the message.

In a further explanation the CGEL states that delimiting commas present the delimited phrase:

> ... as a parenthetical addition rather than an element on a par with
>   the preceding element in terms of information packaging.

Since, in your examples, both the average number and the total number would seem to have equal weight, I see no reason to use delimiting commas.

Answer (score 0):

In the first and second sentences, you don't know if dogs and cats are counted as two separate species, or just together as common pets.

The third sentence is perhaps somewhat heavy, but perfectly clear.

Comment: On the other hand, any ambiguity in the introductory sentence is not critical because the table column headings will clarify it. So a long-winded title would be unnecessary.